# Adding a file to Spring Boot's classpath

Tags: spring, spring-boot, war

I have `server.yml` file that contains **Spring Framework only** properties like port number, context root path, application name.

And, I have a `applicationContext.xml` that has the following:

```
<util:properties id="springProperties" location="classpath*:my.properties">
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath*:my.properties"
        local-override="true" properties-ref="springProperties" />
```

`my.properties` file resides in `src/main/resources` dir of the project.

So then, I can access properties from my java classes like:

```
@Autowired
@Qualifier("springProperties")
private Properties props; 

public String getProperty(String key){
    return props.getProperty(key);
}

or like `${my.prop}`
```

When I build war and run Spring Boot (`java -jar server.war`), internal `my.properties` resolves, and everything works as expected.

However, I wanted to override that file with the external `my.properties`. 
I read https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

I tried to run something like:

`java -jar server.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:/my.properties` or

`java -jar server.jar --spring.config.location=my.properties`

But the only properties I can override by this are from my `server.yml`. Meaning, I can override port number, or application name. But the internal `my.properties` is never affected.

Am I doing something wrong? I understand that external `my.property` simply should be in a classpath, then it overrides internal `my.property`. But it never happens.

Comment: Have you tried to do this without the qualifier of `springProperties` for this configuration. The copy of `my.properties` you are loading externally likely is not affecting that context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @PropertySource({ "classpath:override.properties" }) to add extra files from classpath and then use Environment object to get the values or @Value annotations for the values

```
@PropertySource({ "classpath:other.properties" })
@Configuration
public class Config{
    @Autowired
    private Environment env; //use env.getProperty("my.prop")

    @Value("${my.prop}")
    private String allowedpatterns;
}

@Component
public OthenClass{

    @Autowired
    //If this class is not component or Spring annotated class then get it from ApplicationContext
    private Environment env; //use env.getProperty("my.prop")

    @Value("${my.prop}")
    private String allowedpatterns;
}
```

If you are using Spring Boot below code can be used to get ApplicationContext

```
ConfigurableApplicationContext ctx = app.run(args);

Environment env = ctx.getBean(Environment.class);
```

Comment: After above, I had to just run:
`java -jar server.jar --spring.config.location=my.properties`

Comment: You can put properties files in the resources directory as well. Spring boot will pick up files from the class path.